# How can I store private assets in OSX application with cocoa

Tags: macos, cocoa

On iOS, there is a private bundle where the assets (3D models, plists, etc.) are stored. There is not direct access to those assets for the user, so they are stored in a "secure" location.
But Mac osx applications are stored in a folder where the access is quite simple.

Is there a way to store assets in a secure bundle? Something similar to iOS apps?

Comment: Nothing is off limits in OSX — If you're wanting to secure something you'll need to encrypt it.

Comment: But in my case, I have to make a video in a secure way. The idea is to have the video only accesible using the app. So, I can't encrypt the video while I am generating it.

Comment: Why can't you do that? You can store the stream in an encrypted container at least.

Comment: So, how I can do a encrypted container? Have you any sample or documentation about this? I am not used to use encryption solutions.

Comment: There is an App Just for this https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/loot-locker/id1014080794?mt=12

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quick version: whatever you may do, a motivated user will get the data he want. Plus crypto is hard.

Long version: A problem you'll start facing as soon as you'll manipulate encryption is key management: if your application have any way to recover the key (hardcoded keys are the easiest, FYI), then a motivated user will get his hand on it.

Anyway, if you're still motivated to encrypt your content, you should get your hand on an AES implementation, and write an interface that'll encrypt the data then write them to the disk.

The core algorithm is available there: http://www.cs.ucdavis.edu/~rogaway/ocb/ocb-ref/rijndael-alg-fst.c (replace .c by .h to get the header).
To use it, you need a wrapper that will do the following:

- Setup the key, using the following lines:

.

```
#define KEYLENGTH(keybits) ((keybits)/8)
#define RKLENGTH(keybits)  ((keybits)/8+28)
#define NROUNDS(keybits)   ((keybits)/32+6)    
#define KEYBITS 256

(...)

uint32_t rijndaelKey[RKLENGTH(KEYBITS)];
unsigned char key[KEYLENGTH(KEYBITS)]; //You need to fill it with the encryption/decryption key
int nrounds = rijndaelSetupEncrypt(rijndaelKey, key, KEYBITS);
```

- Encrypt your data, 16 bytes by 16 bytes:

.

```
unsigned char plaintext[16], ciphertext[16];
(...)
rijndaelEncrypt(rijndaelKey, nrounds, plaintext, ciphertext);
```

To decrypt the data, simply replace in those functions names Encrypt by Decrypt.

You still have to write the code that'll read the data, and write them to disk, it'll be more efficient if it can be written in C but you can pick those routines and put them in an Objective-C method. Also, I encourage you to read the following wikipedia article: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_mode_of_operation#Common_modes

Crypto is hard, and this is why most of library fail at it :/